# How to connect to Mongodb Atlas Cluster from an EC2 application

Tags: amazon-ec2, mongodb-atlas

Though I can connect to my `Mongodb Atlas Cluster`, from my `express app` on a local machine through the following connection string, but cannot connect when the same app is running on an `EC2`.

```
mongodb+srv://<<username>>:<password>@cluster0.xxxx.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Have set both inbound and outbound rules on `EC2` as "allowed from anywhere" for ssh/http/https/allTCP on both ipv4/ipv6

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. While transferring my app files from local machine to EC2, the .env file did not get transferred. I had used scp -r ... to transfer the app folder.